# flask.ext is empty

Tags: python, flask

I am learning flask but my flask.ext file only has the file `__init__`  , I tried to update flask but it doesn't work.

Comment: Please show what you have tried in more detail

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

flask.ext should be empty (the maintenance branch) or non-existence (the master branch), it had been [this way](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/extensions/) since version 0.8.

All extensions have been moved to its separate packages installable via pip.

Here is a list of extensions:

http://flask.pocoo.org/extensions/

An example of how you would install an extension:

```
$ pip install Flask-Security
```